# What do these numbers in mutt stands for?

Tags: linux, imap, mutt

I am in the `o` `t` mode now, which mails mails are sorted according to thread.

Why don't the numbers start from 2, then 3?

[image: http://i1271.photobucket.com/albums/jj624/bigmeowOoO/what_the_number_29_26_stands_for.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to be the number of lines in the message.

If you are using the mbox format, where mutt has to parse the entire file, then it counts the number of lines in each message as it is reading the mailbox and this count will be shown here.  You may be using IMAP, where mutt does not know the size of a message until it is fetched from the server.  Or you may be using the maildir format, which has a significant advantage over mbox format in that mutt only has to read the headers of each message.  This will usually be much faster, if you have any large messages in your mailbox.  Using the maildir format mutt can still get the number of lines in the message, but only if the message has a `Lines:` header containing this number; it doesn't scan the entire body of each message every time the mailbox is opened, just to count the number of lines.  If the header is not present then 0 will be shown.  The [mutt FAQ](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Maildir) contains a simple [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) script that can be used to add a `Lines:` header to each message that doesn't have one, as it arrives.

If you don't particularly care to see the number of lines in each message but you would like to use the screen space to show something useful, you can set [`index_format`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#index_format) in your `.muttrc` file to a format string of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are the sizes of the respective messages.

Comment: it is not size of mail, if yes, why other  mails is of size zero, which is not true

Comment: It *is* the size of the mail. The other mails are displayed with size 0, because you connect via `IMAP` and have not yet fetched those mails. Thus `mutt` doesn't know their size (yet). Move the cursor to one of the mails shown with size 0, press `enter` to view it, then `q` to return to the index. Notice that the field now shows a message size >0.

Comment: you are right, how to mark ur comment as answer?

Comment: click the check mark on the left